# Geração automática dos Controllers e Views com .NET Entity Framework e MySQL

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, scaffold

**EDIT:** Resolvi o problema abaixo e outros que apareceram depois. Veja minha reposta.

Criei um projeto de Business usando a abordagem Code First do Entity Framework (EF). Tenho um banco em MySQL com 8 tabelas e todas elas se relacionam mesmo que indiretamente. O EF se conectou ao banco e me gerou as classes de contexto e tabelas. Tudo certo até aqui!

Em seguida, criei um projeto MVC, adicionei a referência para minha camada de Business e fui tentar adicionar um novo controlador com as views fazendo o scaffold de uma de minhas tabelas (o problema ocorre com qualquer tabela, mas vou exemplificar com a de Cliente).

`Adicionar -> Novo item com scaffold -> Controlador MVC 5 com modos de exibição EF`

[image: Adicionar Controlador]

E esse erro ocorre:

[image: Erro]

Uma de minhas tabelas possui alguns campos do tipo **enum**. Porém, já removi qualquer referência ao provedor do SQL server e estou deixando apenas o do MySQL. Por que ele ainda tenta o *SqlServer provider*??

**Web.config**

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="AtividadesNovaContext" connectionString="server=****;user id=****;password=****;database=atividadesnova;persistsecurityinfo=True" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, MySql.Data.EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.EntityFramework, Version=8.0.18.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

**Softwares e pacotes instalados**

- .NET Framework 4.7.2
- MySQL for Visual Studio 2.0.5
- MySQL connector .NET 8.0.18
- MySQL.Data.EntityFramework 8.0.18
- EntityFramework 6.2.0

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que pode estar acontecendo?

**EDIT:** Atualizei a versão do *MySQL for Visual Studio* para a 2.0.5 (versão de desenvolvedor). Após isso o erro mudou (imagem atualizada). Adicionei novas informações do sistema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui gerar os controladores e views, mas tive que resolver muitos problemas além dos que postei aqui. Vou deixar listado os problemas com a solução que encontrei.

`Object reference not set to an instance of the object`

- Além de atualizar a versão do *MySQL for Visual Studio*, também colocar temporariamente os modelos no mesmo projeto da interface apenas para rodar o EF.

`Unable to retrieve metadata for 'Cliente'.`
`The store type 'type' could not be found in the SqlServer provider manifest`

- Definir um objeto `MySqlEFConfiguration` para o `DbConfiguration` no início da aplicação. No meu caso, um app ASP.NET MVC, defini na subrotina `Application_Start()` do arquivo `Global.asax`

  ```
  DbConfiguration.SetConfiguration(New MySqlEFConfiguration())
  ```

`Unable to retrieve metadata for 'Cliente'`
`There is no store type corresponding to the conceptual side type 'SByte' of primitive type 'SByte'`

- Usar tipo `Byte` ao invés de `SByte` nos modelos para mapear o `TINYINT` do MySQL

Também tive um problema com o mapeamento do tipo `TIMESTAMP` do MySQL para o `Date` do VB.NET. (Não anotei o erro lançado.)

- Usar o tipo `MySql.Data.Types.MySqlDateTime` e anotar o tipo da coluna para `DateTime`

  ```
  Imports MySql.Data.Types
  '...
  <Column(TypeName:="DateTime")>
  Public Property Horario As MySqlDateTime
  ```